# Hide a field in views if it has a certain value

Tags: 7, views

I would like to hide a field when there is a certain value in it like `999`.

[image: formatter on views ui].

Comment: can you explain more about `trying to add % in front of a field`?

Comment: Hi @usmanjutt84, I want to hide a field when there is a certain value it it like `999`.

Comment: Do you want it to disappear when the user enters the number or when the number has been previously populated? Like when the user types the last 9 does it disappear then? Or if the field is being pulled from the database with the number 999 it is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [views_conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional)

With this module you can create a **views conditional field** that checks for the value of your **population** field and if it is a certain value to display your field.  You will need to have the **population** field included in the view and **excluded from displaying**

[image]

Comment: Hi @GiorgosK - The problem is I want to hide one of the fields when there is a particular value in it like `999` and I couldn't not place php code inside rewrite results. I was wondering if I could do it through formatter.

Comment: Than you should rephrase your question because that is totally NOT what the question says

Comment: it may have been confusing, changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [views conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) module. According to its explanations:

> Views Conditional is a simple module that allows you to define conditionals (if xxx then yyy) with fields in views. Conditions include:
>
> - Equal To
> - Not Equal To
> - Greater Than
> - Less Than
> - Empty Not
> - Empty
>
> Views conditional allows you to output text based on the result of the condition.
>
> How to use Views Conditional in your Views:
>
> 1. Create a view. Add some fields under "FIELDS".
> 2. Click on "ADD" next to fields. Scroll down to "Views: Views Conditional", probably found near the bottom of the list.
> 3. Add and configure fields...
> 4. Choose a field to run a condition against, and provide values accordingly.
> 5. Save, views conditional handles the logic and returns as specified.

I hope this will help you.